# SignalR without proxy class

Tags: javascript, websocket, ecmascript-6, signalr

I have been working with SignalR on a project and we need to make sure that all or certain hub methods are not exposed via the SignalR generated proxy. I have read that you can use SignalR without an auto generated proxy, either by generating a proxy (on dev box) or my "creating the proxy" in the client (I am using the javascript client).

What does SignalR do if I choose the second method ("creating the proxy" in the javascriot client? Does that generate a SignalR proxy like it does when it is auto-generated or does the signalR javascript client simply route requests to and from the server once .on or .invoke events are registered with the js client?

Again, I was not able to get a clear picture from the SignalR msdn pages on how these options work or change how the javascript environment works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can generate proxies manually instead of at runtime by using the `-ghp` options of the `signalr.exe` tool. Alternatively, you can use the client without proxies at all and this is described in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) article.